# How to call the remote store for combobox in extjs v7.5?

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I have a combobox with data downloaded from a remote server. I want a request to be sent every time I click on the combobox, because I want to dynamically set parameters in proxy.setExtraParams(params). I set params in beforeQuery function.
I have this example that I found on the Internet. In my application, the combo works in a similar way.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ij5&view/editor

However, it works fine in version 7.4 and does not work in version 7.5.

The documentation for 7.5 says that when queryMode: 'remote' you have to manually load the store. Where do I call store.load() so that the combo has time to process the parameters for the proxy?

Comment: What happens if you set `autoLoad` to `true`? As I remember you only have to manually call `load` with `remoe` if `autoLoad` is false.

Comment: I set autoLoad to false because I want to load the store only when you click on the combo box. Before this combo box does not know what parameters to send to the server, they are filled in dynamically

Comment: You can try to load the store in a `change` listener of the combo box.

Comment: I've been trying, but сhange event not fires when you just click on trigger

Comment: Do you mean the expand / collapse trigger? There is an `expand` listener on the combo you can use for that.

Comment: Yes, I would like to load the store when I call expand. I added a expand listener, but it only works when you click again in version 7.5 for my example. No reaction the first time you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the autoLoad to true.

Because you do not want to load the store initially, you have to add a listener (as you did) and set the autoLoad.

You just want to call the listener once, because after that the autoLoad is set.

```
        listeners: {
            beforeQuery: {
                fn: function (queryPlan) {
                    console.log('[ComboBox::beforeQuery] set autoLoad to true');
                    this.getStore().setAutoLoad(true);
                    return queryPlan;
                },
                single: true
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution helped me!